# Access Camera Storage via USB Host Mode on Android

Tags: android, io, usb, usb-otg

I'm trying to access the SD Card on my DSLR via USB Host using my OTG cable. I believe this is through PTP. I've seen a couple of apps that could do this w/o root permission also, not only can they access it they can also control shutter speed and stuff. But I'm only interested in accessing the SD Card on the DSLR. I got stuck after connecting to the USB Device. See attached code

```
private void checkInfo() {
        manager = (UsbManager) getSystemService(Context.USB_SERVICE);
        /*
         * this block required if you need to communicate to USB devices it's
         * take permission to device
         * if you want than you can set this to which device you want to communicate
         */
        // ------------------------------------------------------------------
        mPermissionIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(this, 0, new Intent(
                ACTION_USB_PERMISSION), 0);
        IntentFilter filter = new IntentFilter(ACTION_USB_PERMISSION);
        registerReceiver(mUsbReceiver, filter);
        // -------------------------------------------------------------------
        HashMap<String , UsbDevice> deviceList = manager.getDeviceList();
        Iterator<UsbDevice> deviceIterator = deviceList.values().iterator();
        String i = "";
        while (deviceIterator.hasNext()) {
            device = deviceIterator.next();
            manager.requestPermission(device, mPermissionIntent);
            i += "\n" + "DeviceID: " + device.getDeviceId() + "\n"
                    + "DeviceName: " + device.getDeviceName() + "\n"
                    + "DeviceClass: " + device.getDeviceClass() + " - "
                    + "DeviceSubClass: " + device.getDeviceSubclass() + "\n"
                    + "VendorID: " + device.getVendorId() + "\n"
                    + "ProductID: " + device.getProductId() + "\n";
        }

        textInfo.setText(i);
    }
```

Could someone please tell me how can I read then eventually download the photo from the DSLR's SD Card to my android application.

**UPDATE**

So I tried this library https://github.com/mjdev/libaums

Its awesome but the thing is it only supports USB Mass Storage. It wont recognise my camera storage.

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

- Open connection using [UsbDeviceConnection](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/hardware/usb/UsbDeviceConnection.html)
- Open MTP device using [MtpDevice#open](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/mtp/MtpDevice.html#open(android.hardware.usb.UsbDeviceConnection))

Android's documentation uses general MTP terminology but it really only supports the PTP subset, which is good because that is the protocol you are asking about.